# Pythonwin.exe does not indicate the line of code for runtime errors

Tags: runtime-error, pywin32, traceback

This is a tricky problem because it deals with the Pythonwin.exe user interface itself, and not my code.

When I run a file with the following code in it, I would expect that if it errors, it would show the line that it failed on in the traceback output

I literally just create an untainted 32-bit python 3.5 environment, installed pywin32, and opened my testfile.py to run it and here were the results.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dHtO.png)

If you see the line saying

```
File "C:\testfile.py", line 2, in <module>
  foo = 2 #this line works fine, but is identified as the traceback line
```

I would have expected this to point to line 5 and not line 2.
Inside a larger script, this is much more problematic as I need to guess which line caused the error based on the context.

To replicate my situation in an anaconda-based environment:
1. open the Anaconda Command Prompt
2. run the following lines to generate our environment

```
set CONDA_FORCE_32BIT=1
conda create -n test python=3.5
activate test
conda install -y pywin32
```

3. Save "testfile.py" file with text:

> ```
> #comment
> foo = 2 #this line works fine, but is identified as the traceback line
> a=2
> a=3
> a=b #this line causes the error, but isn't identified
> ```

4. Open PythonWin.exe, open the "testfile.py" file and hit F5 or click Run

And it is not just an issue in anaconda installed environments.
If anyone has any insight into how to make it report the bad line of code, or why it is acting in this way, please let me know. Thanks!